# Cakephp generating lowercase urls with uppercase controller names

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp 2
I've been re factoring my code to use the Html->url() function instead of hard coding web addresses. For those not familiar, I pass a mixed $url variable containing controller and action names.

My gut tells me I should be defining the controller according to the file name and the action according to the function name inside the controller.
ie:
To route to AdminsController::index() I would say

```
$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller'=>'Admins'
    ,'action'=>'index'
));
```

and that *SHOULD* generate for me the url

```
http://example.com/admins/index
```

Unfortunately, what it is generating for me is

```
http://example.com/Admins/index
```

*notice the uppercase "**A**" in admins.

The purest in me refuses to identify the controller by its inflected name because then what's the advantage of using the url helper function at all? Why wouldn't I just write out the urls myself?

Shouldn't the url function be inflecting the controller names?
Isn't lower case / camel case a part of the inflection process?
Is there any way I can force this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the following route in routes.php, you will then have your nice lowercase url :

```
Router::connect('/admins/index', array(
    'controller' => 'Admins', 
    'action' => 'index'
));
```

EDIT: other suggestion, you can also look into defining a custom route that would automatically lower case action and controller when parsing a route url:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes

EDIT2: just got an other idea. You can wrap Html helper into a custom one that performs what you want.

In View/Helper/CustomHtmlHelper.php :

```
<?php
App::uses('HtmlHelper','View/Helper');

class CustomHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {

public function url($url = null, $full = false)
{
    if(is_array($url)) {
        if(isset($url['controller']) {
            $url['controller'] = strtolower($url['controller']);
        }
        if(isset($url['action']) {
            $url['action'] = strtolower($url['action']);
        }
    }
    return parent::url($url, $full);
}
```

In Controller/AppController.php :

```
public $helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'CustomHtml'));
```

I haven't tested, so there might be errors in code. But this is the idea.

Comment: I'd have to do that for all my controllers?

Comment: I guess yes.. But i edited my answer to share other possible solutions.

Comment: The CustomHelper seems like the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the to use the HtmlHelper, you will need to always format your actions/controllers and plugins thus:

```
$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller'=>'admins'
    ,'action'=>'index'
));
```

or:

```
$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller'=>'controllers'
    ,'action'=>'some_other_action'
));
```

Cake will take care of inflecting everything. Just pass the lowercased underscored versions. Invluding if your action is (someOtherController() in the above example)

It's the same in your URLs - you access /admins/, not /Admins/ - the helper works the same way.

Comment: I'm saying I want to be able to write the controller names with a capital letter. 'controller'=>'Admins' and have it still render a lower case url

Comment: Then you will need to create a custom route to manipulate that before the url is generated. It's the cookbook how to do that. Or you could create a helper to accept the capitalized controller name as a  wrapper around the default HTML helper and defer that lowercase version to the HTML helper.